# Unable to Fetch Keychain Certificate Information from mac

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, command-line-interface, keychain

I am facing  a weird issue for an Command line application created from Xcode . I am running a script to fetch expiry date of one of the certificates available in Keychain access in Mac using the below command

```
security find-certificate -c "CertificateNameHere" -p | openssl x509 -text | grep "Not After"
```

When I run it locally through Xcode I am able to fetch the date. But when I Run the app as a service from one of the Library folder the expiry date is not fetched. Instead I am getting a error

```
PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:684:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Though the certificate is trusted

I tried lot of solutions like Trying to find a proper solution to get the expiry date of one the certificates available in keychain but there is no luck. So I am posting it in stackoverflow. I tried another solution to use Mac Xcode security framework to fetch the date using swift but The issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable reason to your trouble is access permissions.

When the script is run as a service it has another user and different/none environment context (Like `crontab` service).

You can fix this by providing the service with proper login user, and initialize the service with proper `source` command to respective `.profile` or `.bash_profile` script.